# IdentityDbContext not creating tables with DropCreateDatabaseAlways

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I'm working on this WebApi project where I'm using latest version of authentication.
My two Context setups looks like this, one is autogenerated for authentication and one is my own dbcontext for other tables:

**ApplicationDbContext for Authentication tables**

```
public class IdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public IdentityContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {

    }

    public static IdentityContext Create()
    {
        return new IdentityContext();
    }
}
```

**MyDbContext**

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateInitializer());
        this.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       //FluentApi
    }
}
```

**DropCreateInitializer**

```
public class DropCreateInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Context>
{
    protected override void Seed(Context context)
    {
        // Seeding works nice here
    }
}
```

My problem is as soon as I got this working with DropCreateDatabaseAlways and seed, it doesn't recreate my tables for the authentication. I just can't figure out why?

Please help!

Kind regards, Haris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only creating and setting an initializer for the `Context` class.

If you want your `IdentityContext` class to also drop and recreate always, you need to implement an additional initializer for that class:

```
public class IdentityDropCreateInitializer : 
    DropCreateDatabaseAlways<IdentityContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(Context context)
    {
        //Seed identity tables here
    }
}
```

And then assign that to the `IdentityContext` like so:

```
public IdentityContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new IdentityDropCreateInitializer());
    }
```